# WP7/8 changing InputScope dynamically after an event using C#

Tags: c#, events, microsoft-metro, windows-phone, inputscope

I'm making an app for Windows Phone, I've been trying for ages to get the InputScope of the main text box to change when the orientation is changed to landscape (so that the keyboard takes up less space in landscape without the autocorrect bar), and back again.

I experimented with a second text box and hiding the others upon an orientation change, but this did not work neatly. :P

Try as I might I can't get this to work and can find no way to change the InputScope value after the OrientationChangedEvent argument, which has worked nicely in changing the position of the elements of the page around orientations.

I'm still fairly new to developing apps with C# and XAML, and I hope there's a nice easy way to set the InputScope of my text box that one of you awesome people could show me!

-EDIT : Here's the event handler, everything inside there works absolutely fine, but any way I try to add anything to do with InputScope does not work :(

```
private void MainPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.Portrait))
        {
            //Portrait
            PlaceholderText.FontSize = 29.333;
            PlaceholderText.Padding = new Thickness (0,0,0,0);
            MainTweet.FontSize = 29.333;
            MainTweet.Padding = new Thickness (12,8,12,8);
            Counter.Margin = new Thickness (0,212,28,0);
        }
        else
        {
            //Landscape
            PlaceholderText.FontSize = 23;
            PlaceholderText.Padding = new Thickness (8,0,0,0);
            MainTweet.FontSize = 22;
            MainTweet.Padding = new Thickness (16,8,180,0);
            Counter.Margin = new Thickness (0,-18,28,0);
        }
    }
```

MainTweet.Text is the textbox that the keyboard is focusing on by default, when the page is changed to landscape I'd love to be able to change this from the "Search" InputScope to another, probably "URL". The stuff currently in there rearranges elements on the page nicely when the orientation is changed, I appreciate it might not look that neat...

Comment: can you post some code to see where can we help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple "orientation" states in the enumeration - not just `Portrait` and `Landscape`. The following worked for me to change the scope (on Windows Phone 7.5 emulator):

```
if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape
    || e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight
    || e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
{
    InputScope inputScope = new InputScope();
    InputScopeName inputScopeName = new InputScopeName();
    inputScopeName.NameValue= InputScopeNameValue.Url;
    inputScope.Names.Add(inputScopeName);
    textBox1.InputScope = inputScope;
}
```

So you'd drop that into your `MainPage_OrientationChanged` event handler.

Comment: THANK YOU for being extremely helpful! I'll work that in now and see :)